# Copy Sheet and name it as a number with leading zero

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheet with tabs that range from being named "1" to "53".

I would like to name sheets with a 0 first if the value is below 10 - 01, 02, 03 etc.

Here's the current code

```vb
Sub CopySheet()

Set ws = Sheets("01")
curName = Sheets("Data").Index + -1

ws.Copy Before:=Sheets("Data")
 
Set wsNew = Sheets(Sheets("Data").Index + -1)
 
wsNew.Name = curName + 1

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Format function in the following way to ensure that if `curName + 1` is a single digit then it will be prefixed with 0.

```
wsNew.Name = Format(curName + 1, "0#")
```